# error: error launching Studio Failed to load JVM DLL

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, jvm

I´m using Android Studio for coding Dart/Flutter. I tried to open my "build.grandl" and than I got this error. When I click on my Grandl file, Android Studio opens and showes the error below. Does anybody know what the solution for that error is? A screenshot of the error is "in" the link.

[screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcnGj.png)

Comment: can you open a command line and type this command: java --version

Comment: have you defined path of java JDK in system variables?

Comment: @RemonShehatta I don´t use Java. I use Dart with Flutter.

Comment: @SandeepSharma how does that work? Sorry I´m a complete beginner

Comment: Hi, @SOSvideo . it's OK. if you have any questions please ask them. if my answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that Android studio needs Java in order to run.

it seems from the error message that you just need to set up your environment variables path.

Follow those steps:

1 - in start menu search for Environment variables
[image]

2 - choose environment variables
[image]

3 - you need to find your PATH variable and add java path to it
[image]

you can check the steps [here](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)

let me know if this solves your problem in the comments!

Answer (score 0):

Check the java version mentioned by @RemonShehatta and then go to environment variables in your computer :

Step 1: [image: Step 1]

Step 2:[image: Step 2]

Step 3: go to Path edit.
[image: Step 3]

Step 4:[image: Step 4]